# How to execute unit tests with the debugger in mixed mode? (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging, mixed-mode

I'm fixing some unit tests and I need to debug them. The callstack is mixed (there are managed and unmanaged DLLs) so I need the debugger to be in mixed mode.

As far as I've seen if you start a native unit text the debugger is in native mode and if you start a managed UT the debugger is managed.

Is there a way to set it up in mixed mode?

Thanks in advance mates.

EDIT: To clarify things, what I do to debug is to click the "Debug" button from the Unit Test list available inside Visual Studio. If I do that over a managed test the debugger starts in managed mode, If I do that over a unmanaged test (C++/CLI) then the debugger starts in unmanaged mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. First of all if you are in a C# project enable the "unmanaged code debugging".

After that run the UT from the "Test Results" windows with the button "Debug Checked Items".

Looks like its a bug at the 2008 edition and its fixed in the 2010.